# send GET request from app WP REST API

Tags: java, android, wordpress, rest, android-studio

I have installed the WP REST API plugin on my domain.When I send a GET request to get my sites posts from web browser, it displays a bunch on HTML (http://honeymarket.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts). Now how do I send this request from whitin my app? Sorry for the dumb question but google is turning up empty.

Also how do I get the data from my GET request to show up as posts instead of HTML in my app?

Comment: please use `postman` a much better client to call `webservices`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap thanks for the reply, but isn't postman just for testing api's? I want to actually sent a GET request **from** my app. Can postman help me with that? If so could you tell me more? Thanks.

Comment: postman used to check wheather your webservice working properly or not ? It is just a tool to call a Web-Service not from inside any android app @Rui Zhe

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this ? How to call web-Services in `java/Android` ? If you are looking for this code then explore this => [How to Get Web-Service Call using java Code](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientPost {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }

    }

}
```